# Javascript improve regex to match number chunks of 3

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get a number chunks of 3 if i could by example if i have the number `22345678` i want to get `['22','345','678']`. Using the following regex

```
/(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g
```

I get `['22','345']`

**Anyone can help me to improve my regex?**

An example in here --> https://regex101.com/r/cF6rN4/1 
and a snippet in this post

```js
console.log('22345678'.match(/(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g));
```

Comment: @BryceDrew: He doesn't have a working version; it doesn't match the final three digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match strings which are followed by digits of length as 3's multiplier or at the end.

```js
console.log('22345678'.match(/\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+$|$)/g));
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/kD0iS7/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

You can avoid the capturing group since it's not necessary.

```
/\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})+$|$)/g
//---------^^^-------------
```

---

**UPDATE :** It can be much more simplified by using `*`(`0` or more repetition) instead of `+`(`1` or more repetition) which helps to avoid the pipe symbol. As ***@torazaburo***'s comment both `(\d{3})*$` and `(\d{3})+$|$` are equivalent.

```
/\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})*$)/g
```

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia : glad to help :)

Comment: Is this not the same as `/\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})*$)/g`?